Am I understanding the purpose of the verifyIdToken and verifySignedJwtWithCertsAsync methods correctly?
I am currently working on allowing users to sign in to my website with Google using OAuth2. I'm using the NodeJS google-auth-library. I've been able to successfully authenticate following this example.
Next, I want to verify the ID token that's returned to me. In the OAuth2 client documentation, I see three methods that seem like they do what I want.

The verifyIdToken method description says:


Verify id token is token by checking the certs and audience


The verifySignedJwtWithCertsAsync method says:


Verify the id token is signed with the correct certificate and is from the correct audience.

Based on these, my understanding is that I'd first want to use verifyIdToken to ensure that the ID token I've received from Google is properly formed. If it is, then I'd want to use verifySignedJwtWithCerts to make sure it hasn't been tampered with and does indeed come from Google.
Is my understanding correct? Is there anything else I should be doing security-wise to make sure this token is legit?
